# Can't install audio drivers, could it mean dead card?

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, motherboard

I assembled a new pc earlier today and have been trying for hours to install the realtek HD audio drivers with no luck. It goes all the way untill the very end of the installation and then says "audio driver failure 0x000000ff".

I've tried the drivers that came on the CD together with the motherboard (ASRock h110m-hg4) and also tried downloading the newest ones from the ASRock website

My question is just the following: Is it possible that I got a new mobo with a dead audio card?

I just kinda want a yes or no answer to that. I've been thinking it might just be dead but I don't really know if being unable to install a driver could actually mean the hardware is not working or is it just software related.

Windows 7 x64 by the way

Comment: Its *unlikely*. Its more likely there's an issue with the driver, or its incompatible with windows 7 somehow.

Comment: https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/solutions-to-fix-issue-install-realtek-hd-audio-driver-failure/ it's more likely one of those solutions will work.  If you have any sort of sound (you should have sound even without a driver) then it's not hardware

Comment: @Ramhound I've tried all that. And I don't have sound. So it's a real possibility that it is dead? That's probably the case then... thanks

Comment: You tried all those solutions in 12 minutes.  It's still very unlikely, so unlikely, its more likely you will win the lottery tonight

Comment: @Ramhound Not 12 mins. I googled it and tried all the relevant results before asking. I'm trying to solve this for hours.

Should I be able to use the line-in without any drivers installed?

Comment: Boot a Linux Live-CD, and try playing an audio file.  BTW it's not a *"card"* (aka circuit board) when the adapter is integrated into the motherboard.

Comment: @sawdust Thank you for the great idea! The audio works on Ubuntu. Post it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct. Still couldn't fix it on windows but at least I know it is a software-only issue.

Comment: Did you try Realtek's own drivers from http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/ - I've found those to be 'better' in some circumstances, though I've never tried for the error you report.

Comment: Tried that. Also tried installing older drivers but no luck. Upgraded to Windows 10 and now it works.